# Add param to rend partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have to render an partial with javascript:

```
$('#chapter_list').html("<%= j(render(:partial => 'icd2')) %>");
```

I tried to add an param :person => person But i didnt had success! Maybe somebody can help me Thanks!

Comment: Before you downvote it, give me answer and we will see!

Comment: What exactly went wrong, what does your controller look like? Can you give more context?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `locals` hash:

```
$('#chapter_list').html("<%= j(render(:partial => 'icd2', :locals => {:person => person})) %>");
```